# How to change output of what's printed?

Tags: java

I have this code that prints out a logic table.
It prints out this table.
P       Q       AND     OR      XOR     NOTp
true    true    true    true    false   false
true    false   false   true    true    false
false   true    false   true    true    true
false   false   false   false   false   true
I'm trying to change all the outputted true and false to 1 and 0. The first line would look like this.
P       Q       AND     OR      XOR     NOTp
1       1       1       1       0       0

I'm not even sure where to begin. I've tried if statements. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class LogicalOpTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean p, q;
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOTp");

        p = true;
        q = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (!p));
        p = true;
        q = false;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (!p));
        p = false;
        q = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (!p));
        p = false;
        q = false;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (!p));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here, but `&` and `|` are bitwise operators.  You need to use `&&` and `||` for logical AND and OR. See [Summary of Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

Comment: logical NOT ( ! ) do the work for you

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy The OP is already using `!p` as the last argument in each `println`, so I'd wager they're aware of it.

Comment: What's an 'if function'?

Comment: if statement haha my bad

Comment: It prints out this table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this, if the prameter of print is true it returns 1, else 0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean p, q;
    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOTp");

    p = true; q = true;
    System.out.print(print(p) + "\t" + print(q) +"\t");
    System.out.print(print(p&q) + "\t" + print(p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(print(p^q) + "\t" + print(!p));
    p = true; q = false;
    System.out.print(print(p) + "\t" + print(q) +"\t");
    System.out.print(print(p&q) + "\t" + print(p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(print(p^q) + "\t" + print(!p));
    p = false; q = true;
    System.out.print(print(p) + "\t" + print(q) +"\t");
    System.out.print(print(p&q) + "\t" + print(p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(print(p^q) + "\t" + print(!p));
    p = false; q = false;
    System.out.print(print(p) + "\t" + print(q) +"\t");
    System.out.print(print(p&q) + "\t" + print(p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println(print(p^q) + "\t" + print(!p));
}

public static String print(boolean stat) {
    if(stat) return "1";        // if stat is true
    return "0";                 // else false
}
```

your table is correct

Output:

```
P   Q   AND OR  XOR NOTp
1   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much. I understand most of the code, I just have a few questions. Is there a reason why the print method is at the bottom? and how come it replaces the output of the first block? Wouldn't the code run the main method first and fail?

Comment: Also why does if(stat) return "1" work and if(stat) {system.out.print("1") not work?

Comment: Sorry, I got excited haha

Comment: * it doesnt matter where the print function is declared
* 'how come it replaces the output of the first block' wtf? can you write it again
* you need to return a variable thats why system.out.println() did not work

Answer (score 0):

To print `1` or `0` for boolean `true` or `false` you should convert the result from boolean to int e.g. like:

```
System.out.println((a|b) ? 1 : 0);
```

Thats a syntax sugar for

```
if(a|b){
   System.out.println(1);
} else {
   System.out.println(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LogicalOpTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean p, q;
    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOTp");

      p = true; q = true;
      String output=(p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t";output=output.replace("true", "1").replace("false", "0");
      System.out.print(output);
      output=repl((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
      System.out.print(output);
      output=repl((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
      System.out.println(output);
      p = true; q = false;
      System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
      System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
      System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
      p = false; q = true;
      System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
      System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
      System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
      p = false; q = false;
       System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
       System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
       System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
}
public static String repl(String input)
{
    return input.replace("true", "1").replace("false", "0");
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
   P    Q   AND OR  XOR NOTp
1   1   1   1   0   0
true    false   false   true    true    false
false   true    false   true    true    true
false   false   false   false   false   true
```

I have done for one line. Please do it for other lines for practice.

Comment: I did, it says that it has been recorded but that votes under 15 reputation will not show publicly):